# Is it safe to implement delegation in python using inheritance like in swift or objective-c?

Tags: python, delegates

Coming from Objective-C & Swift I have implemented following Pattern in Python to use Protocol-based delegation in Python like I would do this in Swift or Obj-C:

```
class DataReceiverDelegate:

    def data_receiver_did_receive_data(self, data):
        pass

    def data_receiver_did_update_settings(self):
        pass

class DataReceiver

    def __init__(self, delegate = None):
        self.delegate = delegate

    def received_data(self, data):
        self.delegate.data_receiver_did_receive_data(data)
```

This is how I use it:

The class which should act as the delegate simply inherits from the `DataReceiverDelegate` class.

```
class DataParser(object, DataReceiverDelegate):

    def __init__(self):
        self.data_receiver = DataReceiver(self)
        # or -> self.data_receiver.delegate = self

    def data_receiver_did_receive_data(self, data):
        print data
```

This works with no issue and is very similar to Swift where Protocols are classes (or structs, not pretty sure), too.

I am having concerns that implementing delegation in Python like this leads to strange issues or is an absolutely no go. So is it safe to handle delegation like that?

Since I currently have no clue about memory handling in Python I am not sure if this might lead to a deadlock because of a "strong reference cycle". So is there a way to define something like a "weak" type?

Also the only issue is that the class who delegates to (`DataReceiver` in this case) has no clue what type `self.delegate` is so code completion in editors does not work.

EDIT:

This is a simplified example just to showcase what I am after. In a real world one would add checks to make sure that delegate is not `None`. Quite similar to "safely unwrap optionals" in Swift.

Comment: If you don't want `delegate` to be `None`, don't make that a default.

Comment: Of course that makes senses! Thanks!

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: The above example is done in 2.7 and has not been checked with newer versions.

Comment: In Python 2 you should use `class DataReceiverDelegate(object):`, not `class DataReceiverDelegate:`, which would give you an 'old-style' class. Then you can just have `class DataParser(DataReceiverDelegate):`.

Comment: Why does `DataParser` know about its `DataReceiver`? Seems like an odd design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing looks fine. You could even leave out the `DataReceiverDelegate` class since methods are only found at runtime, or you could make it an Abstract Base Class for some extra safety and static analysis.

Python 2.7 can handle reference cycles in its garbage collection, although less cycles is probably better. You can also check out weak references if it worries you.

Type hinting in PyCharm can indicate what the type of `self.delegate` is.

Answer (score 1):

I am doing exact the same thing because I saw these examples in swift Libraries and I think the pattern could really help me.
For now I am also concerned about the memory leaking in strong references. But I saw [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/destructors-in-python/) that these types of links in python are called **circular reference**:

> ... it creates an instance of class B which passes itself to class A, which then sets a reference to class B and resulting in a circular reference.

We have pretty much the same **circular reference** here.

I did not find a clear explanation on topic whether we have to manually deal with circular references or not, thus I decided to provide an experiment.

Here is the experiment I tried to fit to your example (just changed class names:)

```
from memory_profiler import profile


class DataReceiver:

    def __init__(self, delegate):
        self.workload = " " * 128 * 1024 * 1024 # this is 'memory weight'
        self.delegate = delegate


class DataParser:

    def __init__(self):
        self.data_receiver = DataReceiver(self)


@profile
def monitor():
    for _ in range(60):
        parser = DataParser()

    print("monitoring at the last point")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    monitor()
```

**output:**

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    74     64.0 MiB     64.0 MiB   @profile
    75                             def monitor():
    76   3557.1 MiB      0.0 MiB       for _ in range(60):
    77   3557.1 MiB    128.0 MiB           parser = DataParser()
    78                             
    79   3515.4 MiB      0.0 MiB       print("monitoring at the last point")
```

It seems like after 60 iterations it consumed about 3.5 GB memory and was not able to get rid of these strong references.

After that we do exact the same thing, but with weakref module to implement the weak reference:

```
import weakref
...

class DataReceiver:

    def __init__(self, delegate):
        self.workload = " " * 128 * 1024 * 1024
        self.delegate = weakref.ref(delegate) # only here is difference: delegate is weak reference
...
```

**output:**

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    73     64.1 MiB     64.1 MiB   @profile
    74                             def monitor():
    75    192.1 MiB      0.0 MiB       for _ in range(60):
    76    192.1 MiB    128.0 MiB           parser = DataParser()
    77                             
    78    192.1 MiB      0.0 MiB       print("monitoring at the last point")
```

Now it seems like after each iteration garbage collector is able to remove local instances after each iteration as there are no strong references anymore.

Also important:

You no longer able to call your methods this way:

```
receiver.delegate.method_name_bluh_bluh()
```

Because weakref.ref is a callable type, and to get the referred object you need to call the ref attribute:

```
receiver.delegate().method_name_bluh_bluh()
```

You can do smth like that:

```
class DataReceiver:

    def __init__(self, delegate):
        self.workload = " " * 128 * 1024 * 1024
        self._delegate = weakref.ref(delegate)

    @property
    def delegate(self):
        return self._delegate()
```

So now you can do:

```
receiver.delegate.method_name_bluh_bluh()
```